# File count and size of each folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following batch script which gives the size of each folder in a directory. I need help in tweaking this or creating a new script so it gives the file count of each folders as well:

```
@echo off
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder=%~1"
    if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"

    for /d %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
        set "size=0"
        for /f "tokens=3,5" %%b in ('dir /-c /a /w /s "%%~fa\*" 2^>nul ^| findstr /b /c:"  "') do if "%%~c"=="" set "size=%%~b"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(%%~nxa # !size!
        endlocal
    )

    endlocal
```

Comment: Recursive or just the count of files on level 1? Should folders inside folders be counted as files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the information is already in the output of the inner `dir` command, you only need to change what to retrieve

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in ("%~f1.") do set "folder=%%~fa"

    for /d %%f in ("%folder%\*") do (
        set /a "size=0", "files=0", "directories=0"

        for /f "tokens=1,3,5" %%a in ('
            dir /-c /a /w /s "%%~ff\*" 2^>nul ^| findstr /b /c:"  "
        ') do if "%%~c"=="" ( 
            set "files=%%~a"
            set "size=%%~b"
        ) else set /a "directories=%%~a/3"

        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            echo(%%~nxf # !size! bytes : !files! files : !directories! directories
        endlocal
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this cmd at the end and it will count files in a given dir

```
setlocal enableextensions
set count=0
for %%x in ("%folder%\*") do set /a count+=1
echo %count%
endlocal
```

This is inefficient tho, as you are traversing the whole directory twice. 
Ideally, you need to combine the two FOR loops into one, just scan the dir once and add the size to the size counter and do count+=1 for each.

Try something like *added spacing to show what i added

```
    set "folder=%~1"
    if not defined folder set "folder=%cd%"

    set count=0

    for /d %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
        set "size=0"
        for /f "tokens=3,5" %%b in ('dir /-c /a /w /s "%%~fa\*" 2^>nul ^| findstr /b /c:"  "') do if "%%~c"=="" set "size=%%~b"

        set /a count+=1

        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(%%~nxa # !size!
        endlocal
        )

    echo %count%

    endlocal
```